# Regex: strip all tags except those containing keyword "univ"

Tags: java, regex

```
[introduction][position]Lead Researcher and Research Manager[/position] in the [affiliation]Web Search and Mining Group, Microsoft Research[/affiliation]</b>.

I am a [position]lead researcher[/position] at [affiliation]Microsoft Research[/affiliation]. I am also [position]adjunct professor[/position] of [affiliation]Peking University[/affiliation], [affiliation]Xian Jiaotong University[/affiliation] and [affiliation]Nankai University[/affiliation].

I joined [affiliation]Microsoft Research[/affiliation] in June 2001. Prior to that, I worked at the Research Laboratories of NEC Corporation.

I obtained a [bsdegree]B.S.[/bsdegree] in [bsmajor]Electrical Engineering[/bsmajor] from [bsuniv]Kyoto University[/bsuniv] in [bsdate]1988[/bsdate] and a [msdegree]M.S.[/msdegree] in [msmajor]Computer Science[/msmajor] from [msuniv]Kyoto University[/msuniv] in [msdate]1990[/msdate]. I earned my [phddegree]Ph.D.[/phddegree] in [phdmajor]Computer Science[/phdmajor] from the [phduniv]University of Tokyo[/phduniv] in [phddate]1998[/phddate].

I am interested in [interests]statistical learning[/interests], [interests]natural language processing[/interests], [interests]data mining, and information retrieval[/interests].[/introduction]
```

I'm able to strip all tags from the paragraph above with:

```
String stripped = html.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");
```

But I'd like to keep three pairs of tags in the paragraph, which are `[bsuniv][/bsuniv]`,`[msuniv][/msuniv]` and `[phduniv][/phduniv]`. In other words, I don't want to strip those tags containing the keyword "univ". I can't find a convenient way to rewrite the regular expression. Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `negative-look ahead` assertion here: -

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[(.(?!univ))*?\\]", "");
```

or: -

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[((?!univ).)*?\\]", "");
```

Both of them will give you the desired output. There is only one difference -

- The first one does a negative look-ahead, against the current character, and if it is not followed by `univ`, it moves to the next character.
- The second one does a negative look-ahead against an empty string before every character, and if it is not followed by `univ`, it goes ahead to match a single character.